# How to size a QML Combox to the width of its bigger element?

Tags: combobox, qml

I have a ComboBox, defined as a Component in QML-only code (so no backend) and I'd like to have its width set automatically to its widest element. For now, it takes the width of last selected elements, and therefore its popup is not displaying its content correctly.

This is an mcve

```
Window {
    id: mainWindow
    title: "Test"
    width: 500
    height: 200
    modality: Qt.WindowModal
    flags: Qt.Dialog | Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | Qt.WindowTitleHint | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint
    //color: "#E3E3E3"


    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 25
        columnSpacing: 10
        rowSpacing: 10
        columns: 2

        Label {
            text: "Foo"
        }

        Loader {
            id: loadCombo1
            sourceComponent: niceComboBox
            Binding {
                target: loadCombo1.item
                property: "model"
                value: [{'value': "none",'text': "None"}, 
                {'value': "medium",'text': "Some medium length text"}, 
                {'value': "long",'text':   "A pretty very long string that shouldn't be hidden"}]
            }

        }
    }

    Component {
        id: niceComboBox

        ComboBox {
            id: control
            delegate: ItemDelegate { // requiert QuickControls 2.2
                width: control.width
                contentItem: Text {
                    text: modelData.text
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }
                highlighted: control.highlightedIndex === index
            }

            contentItem: Text {

                text: control.model ? control.model[control.currentIndex].text : ""
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                leftPadding: 10
                rightPadding: 10
                topPadding: 5
                bottomPadding: 5
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter

            }

            FontMetrics {
                id: fontMetric
                font.family: control.contentItem.font.family

            }
            Component.onCompleted: {
                //computeWidth();
            }

            Behavior on model {
                ScriptAction {
                    script: computeWidth()

                }
            }

            function computeWidth() {
                if (control.model == null) {
                    return;
                }

                var longest = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
                    var txt = model[i].text;
                    if (txt.length > longest.length)
                        longest = txt;
                }
                var pwidth = fontMetric.boundingRect(longest).width;
                pwidth += control.contentItem.rightPadding + control.contentItem.leftPadding;
                pwidth += control.indicator.width
                width = pwidth;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that when the `Component.onCompleted` is executed the model has not yet been specified by the Loader. And the computation of the width can not be handled correctly.

I tried to add `Behavior on model` script to detect a change in the model, but it doesn't do anything.

How should I do ?
Thanks

I'm limited to these versions : QtQuick 2.9 and QtQuick.Controls 2.2

[EDIT] I've incorporated @Mitch's comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ComboBox {
    id: control

    model: []

    delegate: ItemDelegate { // requiert QuickControls 2.2
        width: control.width
        contentItem: Text {
            text: modelData.text
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
        highlighted: control.highlightedIndex === index
    }

    contentItem: Text {

        text: control.model[control.currentIndex].text
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        leftPadding: 10
        rightPadding: 10
        topPadding: 5
        bottomPadding: 5
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    }

    FontMetrics {
        id: fontMetric
        font.family: control.contentItem.font.family

    }

    Binding on implicitWidth {
        value: computeWidth(model)
    }
    
    popup.implicitWidth: computeWidth(model)


    function computeWidth(mdl) {
        if (mdl == null) {
            return;
        }



        var longest = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < mdl.length; i++) {
            var txt = mdl[i].text;
            if (txt.length > longest.length)
                longest = txt;
        }
        var pwidth = fontMetric.boundingRect(longest).width;
        pwidth += control.contentItem.rightPadding + control.contentItem.leftPadding;
        pwidth += control.indicator.width

        return pwidth;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Qt 6, you can use the [implicitContentWidthPolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#implicitContentWidthPolicy-prop) property:

```
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ComboBox {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        implicitContentWidthPolicy: ComboBox.WidestTextWhenCompleted
        model: ["String", "A longer string", "A very, very long string"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm limited to these versions : QtQuick 2.9 and QtQuick.Controls 2.2. I should have mentioned this (this is now added to my question)

Comment: You could work around it in Qt 5 by looping through the model, finding the longest string, and passing that to FontMetrics' tightBoundingRect function. Then you could set the ComboBox's width to the width of the rectangle that was returned. That's really the only reliable way to do it.

Comment: Working nice. Thanks. I'll post my solution when working 100%. How to prevent the automatic resizing of the ComboBox when a selection is made except on recomputing it after each selection ?

Comment: If you set the ComboBox's width explicitly it shouldn't resize.

Comment: Well no. I put the code in the ```Component.onCompleted``` ending with a ```control.width=prefWidth```.I put the same code in the ```onAccepted```. For what it worth, the component is in its own file. And the width is not fixed at all. The component is well sized at initialization but is resized after every selection (hence the code in onAccepted) and also at some other occasions which don' seems linked to the combox.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the first suggestions of Mitch